# Use LPAD with raise info

Tags: postgresql

In postgres when I `SELECT LPAD('begin ',50,'*');` it works and shows displays `"********************************************begin "` which is expected.

I want to use the same in a block with displaying parameter. Using below code.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
BEGIN 
    raise info LPAD('begin %',50,' '),clock_timestamp();  
    raise info LPAD('begin here %',50,' '),clock_timestamp(); 
    raise info LPAD('begin here there %',50,' '),clock_timestamp();
    raise info 'begin %',clock_timestamp();
END $$;
```

I want to display messages with fixed width like columns but it throws error, ERROR:  unrecognized exception condition "lpad". Tried many thing but didn't work. Any suggestion to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
DO $$
    DECLARE  a text;
    BEGIN
        raise info 'begin %', lpad(clock_timestamp()::text, 50, '*');
        raise info 'begin %',clock_timestamp();
END $$;
```

Comment: this is bit different what i want. It is adding fixed line of '*' to timestamp but it should depend on length of 'begin ' string. If we have multiple lines, it should display like columns.

Comment: I am not sure what you want, can you show me the intended result, maybe I can figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it.

```
  DO $$
    DECLARE  a text;
    BEGIN
        raise info '% %', rpad('begin',50,'-'),clock_timestamp();
        raise info '% %', rpad('begin here',50,'-'),clock_timestamp();
        raise info '% %', rpad('begin here there',50,'-'),clock_timestamp();
END $$;
```